# Cycle windows with Irssi

Tags: irssi

Is there a shortcut to cycle through irssi windows? I can't change windows because `alt + [number]` is already bound to changing terminal tabs and I like it. How do I change irssi's bindings so HOME cycles to the prev window and END cycles to the next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start irssi and run these two commands

```
/BIND home previous_window
/BIND end next_window
```

The relevant syntax of the `bind` command is:

```
/BIND <key ref> <action>
```

Here are all actions you can bind to key refs:

```
17:23 command                        Run any command
17:23 key                            Specify name for key binding
17:23 multi                          Run multiple commands
17:23 nothing                        Do nothing
17:23 backward_character             Move the cursor a character backward
17:23 forward_character              Move the cursor a character forward
17:23 backward_word                  Move the cursor a word backward
17:23 forward_word                   Move the cursor a word forward
17:23 backward_to_space              Move the cursor backward to a space
17:23 forward_to_space               Move the cursor forward to a space
17:23 beginning_of_line              Move the cursor to the beginning of the line
17:23 end_of_line                    Move the cursor to the end of the line
17:23 backward_history               Go back one line in the history
17:23 forward_history                Go forward one line in the history
17:23 backspace                      Delete the previous character
17:23 delete_character               Delete the current character
17:23 delete_next_word               Delete the word after the cursor
17:23 delete_previous_word           Delete the word before the cursor
17:23 delete_to_previous_space       Delete up to the previous space
17:23 delete_to_next_space           Delete up to the next space
17:23 erase_line                     Erase the whole input line
17:23 erase_to_beg_of_line           Erase everything before the cursor
17:23 erase_to_end_of_line           Erase everything after the cursor
17:23 yank_from_cutbuffer            "Undelete", paste the last deleted text
17:23 transpose_characters           Swap current and previous character
17:23 transpose_words                Swap current and previous word
17:23 capitalize_word                Capitalize the current word
17:23 downcase_word                  Downcase the current word
17:23 upcase_word                    Upcase the current word
17:23 send_line                      Execute the input line
17:23 word_completion_backward       
17:23 word_completion                Complete the current word
17:23 erase_completion               Remove the completion added by word_completion
17:23 check_replaces                 Check word replaces
17:23 previous_window                Go to the previous window
17:23 next_window                    Go to the next window
17:23 upper_window                   Go to the split window above
17:23 lower_window                   Go to the split window below
17:23 left_window                    Go to the previous window in the current split window
17:23 right_window                   Go to the next window in the current split window
17:23 active_window                  Go to next window with the highest activity
17:23 next_window_item               Go to the next channel/query. In empty windows change to the next server
17:23 previous_window_item           Go to the previous channel/query. In empty windows change to the previous server
17:23 refresh_screen                 Redraw screen
17:23 scroll_backward                Scroll to previous page
17:23 scroll_forward                 Scroll to next page
17:23 scroll_start                   Scroll to the beginning of the window
17:23 scroll_end                     Scroll to the end of the window
17:23 escape_char                    Insert the next character exactly as-is to input line
17:23 insert_text                    Append text to line
17:23 change_window                  Change window
17:23 stop_irc                       Send SIGSTOP to client
```

Key refs are either the escaped character e.g. `^X ^Y ^Z`, or they are defined automatically by irssi:

```
17:28  return                  - The return/enter key
17:28  space, backspace        - Space / backspace
17:28  up, down, left, right   - Arrow keys
17:28  cleft, cright           - Ctrl-left/right
17:28  home, end, prior, next  - prior = Page Up, next = Page Down
17:28  insert, delete
```

Comment: I tried binding previous_window to cleft. It works on TTY7 but not on TTY6. Any ideas?